# Scraping - Clean up scrape with non constant data

Tags: javascript, scrape, dataminer

I'm doing some web scraping.

My output data is in Column 1:

***Submission date: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM***

i only need **YYYY-MM-DD**

i've added this script to remove "Submission date: "

```
var cleanup = function(results) {

  $.each(results, function(){                

   this.values[0] = this.values[0].replace("Submission date: ", "");
        this.values[1] = this.values[1].replace("Case number: ", "");

  });

  return results;                           
};
```

How do i remove HH:MM?
keep in mind the data gonna change everytime

Comment: `this.values[0].replace("Submission date: ", "").split(" ")[0]` or `this.values[0].substring(17, 27)` or `this.values[0].split(" ")[2]` PS. What do you mean that data will change? You need to show some examples.

Comment: Submission date: 2019-01-22 10:55
Submission date: 2019-01-22 10:44
Submission date: 2019-01-22 10:44
Submission date: 2019-01-22 10:44
Submission date: 2019-01-22 10:38
Submission date: 2019-01-22 10:38
Submission date: 2019-01-22 10:38
Submission date: 2019-01-22 10:38
Submission date: 2019-01-22 10:38
Submission date: 2019-01-22 10:38
Submission date: 2019-01-22 10:38
Submission date: 2019-01-22 10:38
Submission date: 2019-01-22 10:38
Submission date: 2019-01-22 10:38
Submission date: 2019-01-22 10:38
Submission date: 2019-01-21 17:06

Comment: So it's in a unified format. Next time just edit your question. Any of the codes I added above will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way might be to split the string on its delimiter. Given a string like "2019-1-20 12:30", split at the delimiter, in this case the space:

```
var value = "2019-1-20 12:30";
var parts = value.split(" "); // ["2019-1-20", "12:30"]
var dateOnly = parts[0];
```